# How to store data in realtime database properly under user authenticated key?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, sharedpreferences

I have stored some data in realtime database under autenticated key using shared preferences. I used `SharedPreferences` because I used multiple pages for getting user data. While storing the data it is getting an extra node i.e. "all" node and I have not added this node anywhere in my code. The node should be in flow like (1) User->authkey->age and not like (2) User->authkey->all->age. Because of this extra node I am not able to retrive the data firebase.
What should I do to make it like (1).

The below are the snippet of the database.

[image: These are the number of users]

[image: This is the data under all node]

Below is my code to store the data into my database

```
public class LoginDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etemail_id,etpassword;
    TextView tvlogin_details;
    Button btregister,btback;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    Users users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_details);
        etemail_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmailid);
        etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        tvlogin_details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoginDetails);
        btback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btBack);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        btregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btRegister);
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference=database.getReference();
        users=new Users();
        btregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String email = etemail_id.getText().toString().trim();
                final String password = etpassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    etemail_id.setError("Provide your Email first!");
                    etemail_id.requestFocus();
                }
                else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    etpassword.setError("Enter Password!");
                    etpassword.requestFocus();
                }
                else if (!(email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty())) {
                    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginDetails.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        reference.child("User").child(Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getUid())).setValue(sp);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                                Toast.makeText(LoginDetails.this, "Successfully registered", LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                                startActivity(it);
                            }

                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginDetails.this, "Registration Error", LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginDetails.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             }
        });

        btback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent it1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Preferences.class);
                startActivity(it1);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the answer to this post because second one was closed as a duplicate -

In order to get what you're looking for you'll need to iterate on the list of details you have and set one at a time as a value under your user's UID **OR just create an object with all of the params you need and send the object**.

Example with HashMap to iterate :

```
HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();

SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
hashMap.put("first_name", sp.getString("first_name", null))
hashMap.put("last_name", sp.getString("last_name",null))
hashMap.put("fathers_name", sp.getString("fathers_name", null))
hashMap.put("date", sp.getString("date", null))
hashMap.put("income", sp.getString("income", null))
(.......)

Iterator iterator = hashMap.entrySet().iterator() 
if (hashMap.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next() 
    reference.child("User").child(Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getUid())).child(iterator.getKey).setValue(iterator.getValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that unwanted extra level (`all`) in the database because when you are write the data using:

```
reference.child("User").child(Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getUid())).setValue(sp);
```

You are passing to the `setValue()` method a `SharedPreferences` object:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And **not** the data that is stored in that object. Inside your `sp` object, the data is stored as a `Map` containing key and value pairs. The first key in that object is **all** and the value is your actual data. That's the reason you have that structure. To solve this, simply get the data out from your `sp` object, save it into a `Users` object and write it to the database. In this way you'll have a database tree without that extra node.

Comment: But I have multiple pages to store data that's why I have used shared preferences

Comment: There is nothing wrong in storing the data in `SharedPreferences` and then share it across multiple activities but when you write it to the database, make sure the get the data out first.

Comment: Sorry Sir I am having problem in getting sp object data out and storing that data in Users. Can you please help me with that.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) out. In your case you should use `getString()` method for each property and then pass all those values to the `Users` constructor or save each property separately.

Comment: I was trying to store the values of sp (object) in users(object) but not able to do that.

Comment: Thats sounds basically as another question. In order to follow the rules of this community, please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.